# Why doe not Android let me load JAR file from sd card?

Tags: java, android, performance, adb

I have copied a JAR file to the SD card and have modified the BOOTCLASSPATH to reflect the same in the class path.

```
adb shell export BOOTCLASSPATH=/sdcard/Download/android-async-http.jar:$BOOTCLASSPATH
```

After modifying the class path, I am trying to launch the APK that depends on the specified JAVA library,

```
am start -n com.package.example/com.package.example.MyActivity
```

Now, the activity runs but with out the JAVA Library and I get the following error,

```
Unable to process classpath element '/sdcard/Download/android-async-http.jar'
```

Can someone explain why does this happen?

Comment: I can't answer this question. But why not pack the jar into your APK package?

Comment: how the compiled apk will ever rely on a jar file inside the sdcard.

Comment: whats the content of android-async-http.jar ?

Comment: ok. Actually I want to see the HTTP / HTTPS requests being sent from a 3rd party app which I know uses android-async-http. There is already android-async-http.jar which is part of the 3rd party apk. Now my version of JAR which goes to the sdcard has logs inserted to it. And to ensure that my version of the library is loaded I have modified the BOOTCLASSPATH and launch the apk from the same shell where BOOTCLASSPATH is modified.Everything seems to be perfect .. just that somehow Android does not probably allow classes from being loaded from SD card. why? I see some apps movable to SD card.